# Assigning specific colors to circles surrounding one random circle

Tags: python

I am coding for a project which requires me to draw a grid of 15x15 black circles.  The program will then randomly choose a circle to fill "gold." The circles surrounding the "gold" circle, are to be "tan," the circles surrounding "tan," should be "grey," and all other circles are "white." The colors are revealed when a mouse click is detected over the circle. I was able to draw the black circles, but am having difficulty with randomizing the "gold" circle and filling in the rest of the colors.

```
def circle_grid(game):

    # Create a list that creates 15x15 grid of black filled circles
    Center = Point(30,70)

    # append to a list
    Y = [ ]
    for y in range (15):
        for x in range (15):
            CIRCLES = Circle(Center, 15)
            CIRCLES.setFill("black")
            Center = Point ((Center.getX()+30), (Center.getY())) 
            CIRCLES.draw(game)
            Y.append(CIRCLES)
        Center = Point(30, Center.getY()+30)
```

This is the specific description and image of what is supposed to happen:

[image: screenshot of task]

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: What graphics library are you using?

Comment: Can the list created be a list-of-lists? If so, it would make doing many things easier.

Comment: yes, it can be a list of lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making the grid two-dimensional—a list-of-lists—so that the `Circle`s in it can be referenced by the row and column they are in. Here's what I mean:

```
def circle_grid(game):
    grid_width, grid_height = 15, 15
    radius = 15  # of each Circle in grid
    diameter = radius*2
    x, y = radius, radius  # Center of upper-left-most Circle of grid
    grid = []

    for i in range(grid_width):
        row = []
        for j in range(grid_height):
            row.append(Circle(x+(i*diameter), y+(j*diameter), radius, 'black'))
        grid.append(row)

    return grid

grid = circle_grid(None)

# Print grid of Circles created.
for row in range(len(grid)):
    line = []
    for col in range(len(grid[0])):
        line.append(str(grid[row][col]))
    print(', '.join(line))
```

Doing this will make it relatively easy to access them via `grid[row][col]`, so after deciding on the position of the gold one, changing the color of groups of them around it would become a matter of, adding or subtracting values from the row, col of the gold one.

For example, say you want the put the gold one at a random position on the `grid`:

```
row_gold, col_gold = random.randrange(grid_width), random.randrange(grid_width)
grid[row_gold][col_gold].setFill('gold')
```

Afterwards, the eight tan `Circle`s immediately around it can be accessed relative to its position like this:

```
grid[row_gold-1][col_gold-1].setFill('tan')
grid[row_gold-1][col_gold].setFill('tan')
grid[row_gold-1][col_gold+1].setFill('tan')

grid[row_gold][col_gold-1].setFill('tan')
# grid[row_gold][col_gold]  # don't change the gold one itself
grid[row_gold][col_gold+1].setFill('tan')

grid[row_gold+1][col_gold-1].setFill('tan')
grid[row_gold+1][col_gold].setFill('tan')
grid[row_gold+1][col_gold+1].setFill('tan')
```

and the indices of all the grey ones could also be calculated relative to it in a similar manner (i.e. based on the values of `row_gold` and `col_gold`).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find basic documentation to give you random `x` and `y` values for the gold circle.

Now, what defines "adjacent" in a square lattice?  The tan layer is all the circles that have `x` and/or `y` differing by 1 from the gold's position.  Gray circles have to have one coordinate (or both) that differs by exactly 2.

That's the algorithm.  Can you take it from there?

Comment: So should I use column = randint(0,224) and row = randint(0,224) then use those values for gold circle?

Comment: That's the right idea, but index with your 15x15 grid, not at the pixel level.

Comment: Hint: use `col` for the variable name: that will align nicely with `row`, and your code will be easier to copy-paste and read.